# What is the period of y = cot 2 πx?

Tags: trigonometry

I know period = $2π / B$.

The equation is $y = \cot (2 πx)$.

I think period is one of these three things:

> $1)\;2π / 2π = 1$
>
> $2) \;2π / 2 = π$
>
> $3) \;2π / π = 2$

None of these answers are correct. It has to be either $1/2, 1/4, π/4$, or $π/2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try $\pi/2\pi$.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you! Why is 2π in the denominator and not the numerator to solve the equation? I thought period = 2π/B?

Comment: Do you mind saying what $B$ is, or is that something I'm supposed to know?

Comment: The default period for $\cot x$ is $\pi$, if you augment it by $a$, i.e. do $\cot(ax)$ the new period is always $\pi/a$. In this case you just happen to have $a=2\pi$. Your use of $2\pi/a$ is from $\sin ax$ or $\cos ax$ where the default period is $2\pi$, but it's always the default over the multiplier.